# How many ways for an android service to communicate with other components within the same application

Tags: android, service

In Android, given a specific `Service`, how many methods exist for that `Service` to communicate with other components (activity, content provider, receiver, other services)?

As far as I know, there are at least 7 methods:

1. startService
2. AIDL/bindService
3. sendBroadcast
4. startActivity
5. notification
6. messenger mechanism
7. Ashmem

Are there any others?

Thanks.

Comment: 8. Use an event bus. Ex: Otto - http://square.github.io/otto/

Answer (score 1):

Like [gunar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051783/gunar) said, you can also use an **Event Bus**.

The most popular are:

- [Otto (square)](https://github.com/square/otto)
- [EventBus (greenrobot)](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

The documentation it's self explanatory but if you need help to get started let me know.

Regards,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

If you want to classify them, then I would do it as following.

> 1. Communication using Intents

- Broadcast intents (global and [local](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html))
- Component intents (start activity, start service)
- System notifications

> 2. Interprocess communication (IPC), can be used for in-process too.

- [Bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)
- [Using Messenger](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger)

> 3. Communication via shared objects.

- Using Singleton (e.g. application or other singleton classes)
- Using event bus (EventBus, [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus), Otto)